# How do I get multiple data from another page?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I am using the code
`final username = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateAccount()));`
to get `username` data from  a different page `CreateAccount`. How can I structure it to also get, say `bio` data from another textfield on the same `CreateAccount` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@osodo While navigating back from `CreateAccount` page you can pass data to previous page. Have a look on below code.

Create ProfileModel

```
class ProfileModel{
  String username;
  String bio;
  String email; 
  ProfileModel({this.username,this.bio,this.email});
}
```

Code for Page -1

```
final userModel = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateAccount()));
if(userModel != null && userModel is ProfileModel){
   print(userModel.username);
   print(userModel.bio);
   print(userModel.email);
}
```

Code for `CreateAccount` page

```
void submit(){
 String username;
   /*
     Implement your other logic here ..
   */
   var user = ProfileModel(username:"John", bio:"Some random bio", email:"john@gmail.com");
   Navigator.pop(context,user);
}
```

Comment: The code actually works as it is. My question is how do I get data from another textfield apart from the username?

Comment: You can create a profile model and store data in it and send back on previous screen just like we did in case of `username`.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to programming. How do I do that?